# Find values of $x$ for which the sum converges $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{(1+\sin(1/k))x^k}{k}$

Tags: calculus

This is a homework problem I'm having some trouble with. I'm supposed to find the values of x for which the series converges.

$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{(1+\sin(1/k))x^k}{k}$$

I used the ratio test and found that it converges for $\text{abs}(x)<1$ but when I checked my work on wolfram it says the ratio test is inconclusive. Have I overlooked something here?

Answer (score 1):

For $x>0$, note that
$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{x^k}{k} \leq \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{\left(1+\sin(1/k)\right)x^k}{k} \leq 2\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{x^k}{k}$$ since $\sin(1/k) \in (0,1)$ for all $k \in \mathbb{Z}^+$. Hence, $$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{\left(1+\sin(1/k)\right)x^k}{k}$$ converges wherever $$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{x^k}{k}$$ converges. (For negative $x$, this is an alternating series and hence converges). Hence, your conclusion is right. Wolframalpha is not to be believed always.

Comment: Actually, WolframAlpha correctly states that the series converges when |x|<1.  The problem is that it incorrectly states that the ratio test is inapplicable.  Of course, your argument is a very natural way to establish the desired result, too.  Although, I do suppose that you mean that x should be greater than or equal to -1 in the application of the alternating series test.

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to ask questions about WolframAlpha, it would be nice to see your exact input.  As far as I know, there is no way to directly ask WolframAlpha about the ratio test, so I assume that you simply entered the sum directly.  Something like so:

[`sum (1+sin(1/k))*(x^k)/k, k=1..inf`](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum%20%281%2bsin%281/k%29%29%2a%28x%5Ek%29/k,%20k=1..inf)

When I do that, the main result I see is the correct statement that the series converges for $|x|<1$.

On the other hand, one of the secondary pods, labeled "Convergence tests" indicates that the ratio test is inconclusive, which is incorrect.  It sounds like you figured this out for yourself, but here's the computation:

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \left|\frac{(1+\sin(1/(k+1)))x^{k+1}}{k+1} \frac{k}{(1+\sin(1/k))x^k}\right| = $$
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \frac{1+\sin(1/(k+1))}{1+\sin(1/k)} \frac{k}{k+1} \left|\frac{x^k x}{x^k} \right| = |x|.$$

Of course, the ratio test states that, if this last limit is less than 1, then the series is convergent.  In this case, you get $|x|<1$, which is an inequality placing a condition on $x$ guaranteeing convergence of the series.  The other answer, by the anonymous user, shows a different approach to proving the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

For $|x|<1$, it converges by comparison with the geometric series $\sum 2 |x|^k$.

For $|x|>1$, it diverges because the general term does not tend to $0$.

But you can deduce that from the ratio test as
$$
\lim \frac{(1+\sin(1/(k+1))k}{(k+1)(1+\sin (1/k))}=\lim \frac{k}{k+1}=1
$$
shows that the radius if convergence is $1$.

On the boundary of the interval of convergence, now.
Note that 
$$
0\leq \frac{\sin (1/k)}{k}\leq\frac{1}{k^2}\qquad \forall k\geq 1.
$$
Hence $\sum \frac{\sin(1/k)}{k}$ converges absolutely. So your series converges at $x=\pm 1$ if and only if the geometric series
$$
\sum_{k\geq 1}\frac{x^k}{k}\qquad x=\pm 1
$$
converges. That is for $x=-1$ by the alternating series test, and not for $x=1$ as this yields the harmonic series.

**Conclusion:** the interval of convergence is $[-1,1)$.

Comment: But, again, that doesn't address the very specific question that the OP asked - Was he correct in concluding that the ratio test implies that the series converges for $|x|<1$ or was WolframAlpha incorrect in saying that the ratio test was inconclusive?  Answer: +1 for mankind!

Comment: @MarkMcClure Right. I was answering to "have I overlooked something?" in general. That is the behaviour for $|x|\geq 1$. The ratio test applies indeed, as it gives radius $1$.

Comment: I guess I was reading "Have I overlooked something" as "Have I made a mistake", which is why I tried to address his use of W|A and the ratio test specifically. Of course, it's hard to say when the OP doesn't indicate his work or his W|A input and doesn't check back!